# Spring Boot Send Mail can't Autowired Bean

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have some problem when autowired my config bean.

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:/spring-config.xml")
public class MailConfig {


private JavaMailSenderImpl impl;
@Autowired
public MailConfig(JavaMailSenderImpl impl) {
    this.impl = impl;
}
 ...
```

Spring say that:

**Could not autowire. There is more than one bean of 'JavaMailSenderImpl' typr.**

**Beans: 1)mailSender (MailSenderJndiConfiguration.class)**
       **2)mailSenderBean (spring-config.xml)**

I don't use jndi bean. And have no idea about it in this app.
How to ignore Jndi bean? Or maybe simpler config Jndi bean instead mine?
Thanks.

Comment: ----------------------------------------**RESOLVED**-------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 0):

Please autowire Interface instead of Implementation

```
 <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
```

but in your class replace `JavaMailSenderImpl` with `JavaMailSender`

Comment: my properties in xml has broken when i change impl to interface 
<bean id="mailSenderBean" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender">

Comment: No no, here when you Autowire please use Interface instead of impl.

Comment: <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">  but in your clasa during Autowire use JavaMailSender mailSender

Comment: What interface?                                                                                                private JavaMailSender impl;
    @Autowired
    public MailConfig(JavaMailSender impl) {
        this.impl = impl;
    }                                                                                                                           It add me third variant bean to inject

Comment: JavaMailSender interface

Answer (score 0):

---------------------------------RESOLVED------------------------------
I add property in xml

```
  <qualifier value="main" />
```

And change code

```
    private JavaMailSenderImpl impl;
    @Autowired
    public MailConfig(@Qualifier("main")JavaMailSenderImpl impl) {
         this.impl = impl;
     }
```

Comment: you should use qualifier only when you have 2 implementation of your Interface. Otherwise you will get exception. So, i think in this case to use qualifier looks like workaround